# Convert an Integer To Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.Changeset

Tags: tfs, type-conversion

I have a TFS build process where I invoke a Powershell command that returns a changeset back to the build process. I would like to associate this changeset to the build itself so that it appears in the build report.

The problem is that the value returned from Powershell is an integer and the variable used for reporting changesets in TFS is of the type:
"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.Changeset"

**Is there a way within the TFS build process to convert an integer to this type?**

If I try to do a direct conversion I get the following error:

> Value of type 'Integer' cannot be converted to
>   'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.Changeset'.

Also note: I've already fiddled around with the Community TFS Build Extensions and it I was unable to find the activities I needed.

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using? Do you get Changeset ID from the Powershell script?

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that the value I get from the Powershell script is the changeset ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be a "Get" action rather than "Convert" action. You need to get the changeset by the returned integer changeset ID and then associate the changeset to build.

```
$tfsUrl = “xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx” 
$chId = “xxxxxx” 
$tfs = New-Object Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollection $tfsUrl 
$vcs = $tfs.GetService([Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.VersionControlServer]) 
$changeset = $vcs.GetChangeset($chId)
```

Comment: This helps a little bit more, I'll have to translate this from Powershell to the weak VB.NET scripts that TFS builds use. If I had a choice I would use Powershell to get the changeset, but you can't return an object from Powershell to a TFS Build.

Answer (score 1):

`Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.Changeset` is the [Changeset Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.changeset(v=vs.120).aspx) which represents a set of changes committed to the repository. It seems you get changeset ID from the Powershell script as you mentioned the value is an integer. You need to use [Changeset.ChangesetId Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.changeset.changesetid(v=vs.120).aspx) of Changeset Class to get the ID of the changeset.

Comment: Would would that look like? Currently I've got:
`Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.Changeset.ChangesetId=MyBuildID`
But this is throwing a "Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference." error

Comment: Partially figured it out, it was the wrong class:
`Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.VersionControlServer.GetChangeset(MyBuildID)`
Now just to fix the error that comes with it:
"Reference required to assembly 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' containing the implemented interface 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.ITfsTeamProjectCollectionObject'. Add one to your project."